# CORS issue while running Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I am new to Ionic2 and i am trying to access some external service through my Ionic 2 application, but application is throwing below error in console.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://xxxxxxxx.xxx.xxxxxx.com/xxx/xxxx/services?xxx-client=007.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

I have also added proxies in **ionic.config.json**

```
{
  "name": "XXX XXX",
  "app_id": "",
  "v2": true,
  "typescript": true,
  "proxies": [{
      "path": "/xxx/xxxx/services?xxx-client=007",
      "proxyUrl": "https://xxxxxxxx.xxx.xxxxxx.com?xxx-client=007"
  }]
}
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Please help me to resolve this issue. *(To prevent copyright, i have replaced original service name)*

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: I think if you tried it in the phone the issue does not occur. It occurs only when you do ionic serve in browser. Also, if you want to make it work in a browser, you need to install this CORS plugin for Chrome - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en Let me know if this works. :)

Comment: You need to setup CORS in your server side. That would depend on your server side technology you have used.

Comment: @SagarKulkarni: Well without using any plugin, i use **chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security** command in RUN prompt (win+r) to run chrome without web security, by which my application is running smoothly. But as this is a temporary fix, i am looking for any code that needs to be added in my project just as i used proxies but i didn't worked for me.

Comment: @suraj: is there anything that i can do at client side to resolve such issues ?

Comment: Did you check it on phone if it works? Without any plugin after building an apk for android or so?

Comment: It didn't worked with my mobile build, i think i need to handle setup CORS at server side as @suraj said

Comment: *response had HTTP status code 500* indicates some failure on the server side—most likely completely unrelated to your CORS config. The only reason your browser shows that CORS error message is just because when the server has an internal failure it doesn’t bother to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the 500 message it sends—which makes sense given a 500 pretty much indicates a complete failure preventing the server from operating normally. So to fix the 500 failure you need to go into the server logs on the server side &see what messages are logged there about the cause of the 500

Answer (score -2):

Just try to install this [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)

UPDATE:

AS I KNOW, the browser has the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). So by default, it will prevent you from making requests to resources exists on another (second) domain. Then installing this extension will allow [cross origin resources sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) on your browser thus you will be able to access that resources. (Supposing that all domains are allowed to access the resources on your second domain )

Comment: Please elaborate on the solution. Why does installing this extension solve the problem and how?

Comment: AS I KNOW, the browser has [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). So by default, it will prevent you from making requests to resources exists on another (second) domain. Then installing this extension will allow [cross origin resources sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) on your browser thus you will be able to access that resources. (Supposing that all domains are allowed to access the resources on your second domain )

Comment: It might be a good idea to update your answer with this knowledge.